Does Stack Exchange answers have the same validity as pre-print sites like arXiv when proving priority?
Say I have done some simple calculations in an answer to a Stack Exchange question, which after a quick search does not have any existing papers detailing the same procedure, or that the few existing papers do not have entirely correct results. However in the moment I do not think it is worth my time to type up a complete pre-print and upload to arXiv, and the idea still needs some developing.
If I ever wish to publish the results, can I use this Stack Exchange answer as proof of my priority for coming up with the idea/calculation, instead of more conventional pre-print sites like arXiv? Will this be respected if there is a dispute over priority?

If your idea is so simple that you refer to it as “simple calculations ... that I do not think it is worth my time to type up” then your question is moot, since the value of the idea is negligible, and no one will ever bother disputing that you came up with it when you did. In that sense, it is also the case that no one will question that you have priority (so your priority will be “respected”). But this is of no consequence: you will not gain any practical benefit from having people recognize that you have that type of priority.
Moreover, in my experience as a frequent reader of MathOverflow and some of the other Stack Exchange sites, the nature of simple calculations of the sort that get posted on Stack Exchange is that they are almost never truly original. It is much more common that they are either identical to or minor variations on well known ideas (or sometimes not so well known ideas that nonetheless experts recognize as being standard in the literature). So it’s quite probable that your priority will be superseded by someone else’s results anyway.
The bottom line is that your question appears to be based on a misconception that simple calculations can be more valuable or original than they typically are.

This seems to be exactly the scenario the OP is concerned about: That simple things indeed typically are not noteworthy, but the occasional pearl is among them. Being rare isn’t a defect, it’s the point.

It would be dangerous for a person to depend on a site like SE for such a thing. While you might be successful in such a claim, note that posts here are infinitely editable, as was your question. This can occur at any time and by most users. Posts are also subject to deletion and some disappear quite completely. So, your claim might vanish by the time you want to make it.
Use a site designed for the purpose you have and that promises permanence and traceability.

To be fair, the change history would indicate when and what edits were made to the post. Still, as you note, SE is not the right tool to use.

@JonCuster, policies can and do change and the management makes no promises that would safeguard the writers interests.

It is pretty clear from the past (more than a) few years that we can't trust anything management says about SE. But the content will live on in the data dumps somewhere on the internet.
